# swift iOS full height table inside a table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

### Goal

I'm trying to create a table where each cell has a table inside of it. These inner tables are not scrollable and need to be full height based on their content size.

### Code

Click [here](https://github.com/mclachlinbrian/table-in-table-cell) to see my repository with an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

ViewController

- Displays a table with a hard-coded array of food groups
- Each table cell is a FoodGroupCell

FoodGroupCell

- XIB with a label and a table (has a corresponding swift file)
- Each table cell is a FoodItemCell
- Has an `@IBOutlet` for the table's height constraint
- Uses a KVO on `contentSize`

  - updates the height constraint to the table's content size
  - calls `updateConstraints` and `layoutIfNeeded` on the table cell

FoodItemCell

- XIB with a label
- Label has a height of 200

### Problems

If I have a height constraint and no bottom constraint on the inner table the cells do not display properly.

[image: FoodGroupCell table with a height and no bottom constraint]

[image: Simulator with a height and no bottom constraint]

If I have a height constraint and a bottom constraint on the inner table the cells appear, but do not adjust their size based on the label's 200 height.

[image: FoodGroupCell table with a height and bottom constraint]

[image: Simulator with a height and bottom constraint]

This is obviously not ideal having a bottom constraint and a height at the same time. It does not seem necessary and xcode throws a bunch of warnings because of it.

Can anyone shed any light on my issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Update

The problem was that I needed to update the constraint priorities, so that the height and bottom constraint could work together. I have updated my repository with the changes.

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood but it seems as though what you might use instead of tableviews inside of a tableview would be the concept of section headers and sections. The header (Fruit, Meat etc.) would be a custom view you can return in the view for header in section. And all cells within that section would contain the data for that section. That way it's a single table view, single data source and could have different data per section.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve. The simple example I setup is just to demonstrate my issue. The actual implementation has data that comes back from an API, which is an array containing many different types of items, sorted by date. Each one of these items would be a different cell in the table view. Each of those items can contain an array of items inside itself, which would also be many different types. Based on the data returned I felt a table inside a table cell was the best approach for the dynamic nature of the payload.

Comment: Oh I see. As for the constraint issue you may be able to work around this by adjusting the priority of one of the two constraints. So that it can adjust itself without being blocked by the constraints all having top priority.

Comment: Wow, that worked, set the bottom constraint priority to 999 and the error messages went away. Applied the same treatment to the FoodItemCell and the cell now takes up the 200 height space. Thanks for your help, feel like I understand constraints that much better now.

Comment: If you post a reply I'll submit it as the answer, want to make sure you get the credit.

Comment: Done, thanks for letting me post the solution to get it as the accepted answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to work around the constraint issue by adjusting the priority of one of the two constraints so that it can adjust itself without being blocked by the constraints all having top priority.